# Marketing Cloud Personalization: How to apply a campaign to multiple elements with the same class

Tags: interaction-studio, personalization

I'm trying to apply a template/campaign to multiple elements with the same class. The content zone is mapped properly, but the campaign is only being applied to the first instance of the class. I'm using a modified version of the "Banner with Call-To-Action" global template. I haven't touched the Clientside Code.

It feels like I need a loop, but I'm not sure where I would put it. Clientside Code in the template? If so, where? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!